# IronPython and pdb.set_trace()

Tags: ironpython, pdb

Does anyone know if IronPython 2.6 is planned to have support for pdb.set_trace() to enable setting breakpoints in an ironpython module? If not does anyone have a suggestion for accomplishing this without pdb?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, IronPython 2.6 supports this.  By default this switches on when sys.settrace is called so frames already on the stack above the caller won't be available.  But with the -X:Tracing option it's available all the time.

Comment: I have tried this with RC3 and I can't get it to work. Here is my code:
import pdb
import sys

print "hello"
pdb.set_trace()
print "goodbye"

I call this with:
ipy -X:Tracing -X:Frames test.py 

and no luck...the breakpoint isn't hit.

Comment: I used -X:Frames and got it to work.  -X:Tracing did not work.